# How can I move a file in Dolphin without moving any data?

Tags: files

How can I move a file (or directory) in Dolphin without using drag and drop and without doing any copying?  Of course, that's just what the shell command **mv** does. Unlike **mv**, cut-and-paste requires moving data, so that's not an adequate solution.

Comment: [Ctrl]+[X] will cut and [Ctrl]+[V] will paste. If you are in a directory different from where you cut from, a paste should act like a move 

Comment: Cut and paste implies moving data; mv does not.

Comment: @PaulA. cut and paste within the same partition shouldnt copy the data; the alternative is open a second window with your destination dir and just drag and drop.

Comment: Are you sure that cut and paste within a partition doesn't move data?  I've assumed it does, but I suppose one would have to look at the code to be sure. Timing a really large cut-and-paste would give an indication, perhaps.

Comment: Nautilus is able to do this explicitly.  Some programs let you change copy into move with the shift key.  The lack of this is a drawback of Dolphin.  It may be doable with drag and drop, but drag and drop doesn't work well when everything is not in a single window.